# Socket.IO(Android)でroomに加入する方法

Tags: android, eclipse, socket.io

ネイティブSocket.IOのAndroid版を使ってSocket.IOを使ったプログラムを作成しています。
参考：http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

環境：
Androidターゲットバージョン：android-19
Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

roomに入るメソッドを調べていますが、見つかりません。

```
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://【Socket.ioサーバ】/");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mSocket.connect();
mSocket.emit("from_client", "Androidだよ");
    ・・・     
}
```

メッセージを送るところまで成功しました。Android版のSocket.IOにはroomに入るメソッドはないのでしょうか？
ご存知の方はご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Room名をURLの後ろにつけるだけで入室できると思います。

`"http://【Socket.ioサーバ】/【Room名】"`